# swift Janus can not publish video, but get remote video successful - can not know reason

Tags: swift, publisher, janus-gateway

im tried to use Janus to call in videoroom. the problem is the remote video success to display, but only publisher can not show in janus videoroom, after check log i see :

`RTCIceConnectionState didChange state 1`

`RTCIceConnectionState didChange state 4`

```
/** Represents the ice connection state of the peer connection. */
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, RTCIceConnectionState) {
  RTCIceConnectionStateNew,
  RTCIceConnectionStateChecking,
  RTCIceConnectionStateConnected,
  RTCIceConnectionStateCompleted,
  RTCIceConnectionStateFailed,
  RTCIceConnectionStateDisconnected,
  RTCIceConnectionStateClosed,
  RTCIceConnectionStateCount,
};
```

After read admin api, i see the document say about my error:

```
Let’s see an example of a “broken” PeerConnection instead:

"components": [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "state": "disconnected",
        "local-candidates": [
            "1 1 udp 2013266431 172.17.0.3 46008 typ host\r\n",
            "2 1 udp 2013266431 143.225.229.138 60710 typ host\r\n",
            "3 1 udp 2013266431 2002:8fe1:1cc3:b:5c48:51ff:fee9:11ef 58925 typ host\r\n",
            "4 1 udp 2013266431 fec0::b:5c48:51ff:fee9:11ef 52486 typ host\r\n"
        ],
        "dtls": {},
        "in_stats": {},
        "out_stats": {}
    }
]
```

`In this example, ICE is “disconnected”, which means the ICE connectivity checks never started at all. As a result, the DTLS and data stats sections are obviously empty, as Janus never got to the point of involving them. What is the cause of the problem here? Looking at the data Janus provides, one thing immediately pops to the eye: there are just local candidates (the ones Janus gathered for itself), but no remote candidates at all: this means that the client failed to send them to Janus for some reason (e.g., your client is not sending trickle candidates) and so Janus can’t do anything to establish a media connection.`

Can anyone explain me the problem, note that subscriber work normal!, **i mean i can get remote  video and display in my phone, but my phone can publish video to janus**

When open rtc error log, i see too much line about:
`(stunport.cc:279): Jingle:Port[0x1248a2e00:audio:1:0:local:Net[en2:169.254.0.x/16:Wifi]]: UDP send of 100 bytes failed with error 65`

RTC log updated below
`https://pastebin.com/EE7Jhz75`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved, coz of proxy server is not auto mapping from ios, google chomre + safari auto mapping.